# Vimeo embed issue on iPhone

Tags: html, iframe, html5-video, vimeo, embedded-video

Here is my dilemma:

I am creating a site that will allow users to submit videos that will be posted to the site. The user submits a Vimeo link and the video gets posted in an embedded format to the site. Unless the creator of the video has a PRO or PLUS Vimeo account, embedded vimeo videos do not work on iPhone 3GS (not sure about iPhone 4, but they do work on iPad).

Is there any sort of workaround to get embedded vimeo videos working on iPhone? Any ideas?

[image]

Edit: I have checked and it does work on iPhone 4. But still not 3GS.

**Embed Code**

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php echo $videos[$i]; ?>?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffff00" width="" height="" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen ></iframe>
```

Comment: I got the same problem with iPhone3G and 3GS. It seems to work on iPhone 4 and 4S and all iPads. Is there anybody who knows a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, by registrate a plus account you can generate a mobile version. Works with all iPhone models.

Comment: The problem is that I am having users submit videos. If that user is not a vimeo plus member, their video doesn't show up on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Well with out any code it's hard to tell, are you embeding the video via iframe?

http://vimeo.com/api/docs/player

Comment: Yes I am using iframes. Here is my embed code:

`<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php echo $videos[$i]; ?>?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffff00" width="" height="" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen ></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with this same issue right now.  My best guess is that the Vimeo videos are encoded in H.264 main profile, whereas the 3GS can only play videos encoded in H.264 baseline profile.

This article has a discussion of the differences:

http://www.niallkennedy.com/blog/2010/07/h264-video.html

It looks like there is probably not an easy way around this issue.  As you indicated, all videos play fine in the iPhone 4 and 4S since they support H.264 main profile.